# trigger different function dependent on window size resize window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two animations, one for mobile and one for desktop. This works well when the page loads, however when you resize the window the animation doesn't change.

for example if you load the page in desktop size the desktop animation plays when you hover on the appropriate section. However, if I resize the browser to 'mobile size' (less than 1000px) the animation for desktop still plays.

I have approached this countless ways and cannot figure out why it doesn't work as expected.

Please see code below:

```
var isMobile = isMob();

function isMob() {
    if($(window).width() > 1000) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    isMobile = isMob();
});

if(isMobile){
    mobileAnimate(); 
}  
if(!isMobile){  
    deskTopAnimate();
}

function deskTopAnimate() {
    $('.hover-zone').mouseenter(function(){
        desktopAnimateOut.play();
    });

    $('.desktop-close').click(function(){
        desktopAnimateOut.reverse();
    })
}

function mobileAnimate() {
    $('.hover-zone').click(function(){
            animateOut.play();
        }
    });

    $('.mobile-close').click(function(){
        animateOut.reverse();
    })
}
```

Comment: Typo in mobileAnimate()? You use .click() for "hover-zone" instead of .mouseenter().

Comment: @rveerd i want to use click for mobile, and mouseenter for desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions

```
if(isMobile){
    mobileAnimate(); 
}  
if(!isMobile){  
    deskTopAnimate();
}
```

are evaluated only at the begining. I think you have to put them into funtion resize, like

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  isMobile = isMob();
  if(isMobile){
      mobileAnimate(); 
  }  
  if(!isMobile){  
      deskTopAnimate();
  }
}
```

Comment: i know now what the issue is, the hover function gets linked to the hover-zone on desktop, but then when you go to mobile this is still linked. i need to figure out how to remove this

Comment: Yes, you have to unbind the link. Try with `$('.hover-zone').unbind("mouseenter")` and `$('.mobile-close').unbind("click")` (and the other objects) before re-link them

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `window.matchMedia()` function.

```
var mm = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 1000px)");
mm.addListener(l => {
    // Handle changes
    if (l.matches) {
        mobileAnimate();
    } else {
        deskTopAnimate();
    }
});
// Initial value
if (mm.matches)
    mobileAnimate();
else
    deskTopAnimate();
```